# Вызов метода через Vue в HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть цикл v-for для Vue, нужно при его прохождении каждый раз вызвать метод с передачей параметра, как это сделать.

```
                <div class="test_block" v-for="com in list">
                        <input type="radio" это_взываемый_метод(com.first) class="btn_like" v-bind:placeholder="com.IDUser" value="button_like">
                </div>

                var app = new Vue({
                  el: '#app',
                  data:{list: []}
                  components: { list },
                  methods: {
                    это_взываемый_метод (параметр) {
                      console.log(параметр)
                    }
                  }
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы явно пытаетесь решить какую-то задачу. И придуманный способ не самый лучший. Я не рекомендую вам так делать, но вот ответ на ваш вопрос:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  methods: {
    method(param) {
      console.log(param)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="test_block" v-for="com in list">
    <input type="radio" :fake-attr="method(com) && undefined" class="btn_like" value="button_like">
  </div>
</div>
```

`&& undefined` нужен чтобы `fake-attr` не записался в итоговую разметку в случае, если `method(com)` вернет результат отличный от `null`, `undefined`, `false`

Comment: Спасибо ответ сработал, но возникает проблема с получение объектов document.getElementById("к примеру 1"); внутри цикла, он возвращает всегда null, а вне его все работает

Comment: Скорее всего, это происходит потому, что элементы, которые вы пытаетесь найти методом `getElementById()`, еще не существуют.

Comment: Но Vue где то его обрабатывает, как его получить